# How can I load cloud-config from a remote source like S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coreos, cloud-init

I am running a CoreOS server on Amazon EC2. The user-data I would like to provide the server on boot is too long for my Launch Configuration to handle. How would I solve this?

The path I'm going down is to send the cloud-config yaml file to S3, start the server up with an IAM-Role that has access to the object on S3, download it, verify it, and install it. The "install it" part is proving to be tricky however.

My condensed cloud-config that is trying to reference the config on S3:

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  update:
    reboot-strategy: off

  units:
    - name: extra-cloudinit.service
      command: start
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Gets S3 cloud-config and runs it.

        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        RemainAfterExit=yes
        ExecStart=-/bin/mkdir /cloud-init
        ExecStart=/bin/docker run --rm -v /cloud-init/:/data/ pebbletech/docker-aws-cli aws s3 cp s3://my-deployment/cloud-config/cloud-init-v1.yaml /data/
        ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'cd /cloud-init/; echo "efc158573d28193f63887c911ac5b01af287d2dd  cloud-init-v1.yaml" | sha1sum -c -'
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/coreos-cloudinit --from-file=/cloud-init/cloud-init-v1.yaml
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl restart docker
```

I add a drop-in for docker in the cloud-config that is hosted on S3, so I need to restart it. The problem is  the script never restarts docker. Running `ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl daemon-reload` seems to kill the whole thing and restart it and systemd get's caught in a loop.

What am I missing? This seems like a pretty common use case? Is this an anti-pattern? As a work around I can move some things into the user-data cloud-config, but then I have main config in 2 places which seems weird. I'd just like to reference that object in S3 as user-data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ignition, which is the successor to cloud-init. Ignition runs *before* systemd starts, so you can avoid all of those issues.

Ignition can fetch a remote config:

```html
{
  "ignition": {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "config": {
      "replace": {
        "source": "http://example.com/config.json",
        "verification": { "hash": "sha512-0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You provide this into the user-data just like you would cloud-config. Docs for a fetching a remote config: https://coreos.com/ignition/docs/latest/examples.html#replacing-the-config-with-a-remote-config